# Asp.Net Core 2 after publishing get error "Layout cannot be found"

Tags: layout, asp.net-core, publishing

After publishing the application I get the error:
"InvalidOperationException: The layout view '_Layout' could not be located. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/_Layout.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.GetLayoutPage(ViewContext context, string executingFilePath, string layoutPath)"

The Layout is there in the Views/Shared folder and the application works with it locally, so this must be something wrong with the publishing.
Unfortunately in the published app the views appear all contained into a single dll file and I cannot do anything to solve the problem.
Could be anything in my code that makes the publisher to forget to add the _Layout.cshtml view?
I have a reference to the layout in my _ViewStart.cshtml
That should be for all pages. Without Layout my app is doomed and I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok After many tries I found the cause of why the publishing did not include my layout page! It was so tricky that I am amazed. I hope this helps other people!
When you right-click on the layout file (or on any other file) you have the menu with the option properties. I opened the properties of the layout file and I noticed that there you have an "advanced" option: "Compilation Action". My option was set to "none" that means the file was not compiled and therefore not included in the publishing. I put it on "Content" and tried the publishing again and all went well, this time the layout file was compiled and included in the publishing.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time! Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this happened to me when i was copying one file from one project in the solution to another, it was set to "Content" in the source, but when i pasted the file, it was set to "None".

Answer (score 0):

In my case the "Copy to output directory" was set to "Do Not Copy", I changed it "Copy if newer" and then it work.
[image]